# Any refactor tool which can do the following in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, encapsulation

change the field from public to private and want change every reference of it be replaced with getter/setter?

Comment: Haha. This question should be shown to all people asking here why public variables are evil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the field -> Refactor -> Encapsulate field

Answer (score 0):

For replacing `public` with `private`, your best bet is probably to run a search and replace across your class.  To generate getter and setter methods there is a command for that [under the context menu in](http://www.eclipse-blog.org/eclipse-ide/auto-generating-getters-and-setters.html) `Source -> Generate Getters and Setters...`